# Grouping drawables by screen size instead of density

Tags: android

I've read this article [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), but still don't get one thing and need an advice.

I have 3 psd files which contains design for 240x320, 480x800 and 720x1280 screen resolutions.

Since I don't know densities, looks like I should group drawables by screen size. I'm right?
I'm confused, because app should support tablets (which usually are mdpi) and hdpi phones. Or it's not correct design files?

Comment: You shouldn't go by screen resolution, as (1) you are almost never going to be able to cover all screen sizes, e.g. my phone is.320x480 and my mate's tablet is 480x960.  I bet there's a dozen more different resolutions; and (2) even with the same resolution, different pixel density will make your designs look different on different devices.  Hence I suggest that you stick with pixel density and avoid static design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't go by screen resolution, as

1. You are almost never going to be able to cover all screen sizes, e.g. my phone is.320x480 and my mate's tablet is 480x960. I bet there's a dozen more different resolutions; as David Scott pointed in his answer, there are definitions of what "small/normal/large/x-large screens are, however the key words in those definitions are **at least**: 470x320 is normal screen, but so are 480x320 and 560x480; even if there's no device today with a particular resolution, there may be one tomorrow.
2. Even with the same resolution, different pixel density may make your designs look different on different devices.

Hence I suggest that you stick with pixel density and avoid static design.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by screen size or screen density or both. It's all explained in that link.

The screen sizes are:

> ```
> xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
> large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
> normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
> small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
> ```